# Is it possible to use a Li-ion power tool battery while on a charger?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, ups

My plan would be to use a [20 V (x2) power tool battery](https://www.aldi.co.uk/activ-energy-20v-40v-battery/p/097877273773600) with a [step-down converter](https://www.az-delivery.de/en/a/downloads/-/9a56dbc178966e15/22019c0aadc13944) to power a 12 V radio.

I would also like to be able to power the radio from the wall through the [battery charger](https://www.manualslib.de/manual/524276/Activ-Energy-Xyz563.html#manual), similar to how a UPS (or laptop/phone) work, so the question is, is this possible?

Can I put the battery on the charger and connect the DC/DC converter to the leads of the charger that go to the battery to operate seamlessly on wall and battery power?

I have looked around a bit but am still not sure if this would or would not work. On Reddit, I found [this](https://old.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/wiki/batteries#wiki_battery_in_a_circuit), which would describe my situation, although I am not sure if the BMS shown there is how my battery works.

Or more specifically, if the charger just supplies power and the BMS of the actual battery manages the charging, or if the charger actually charges the battery as described in [this video by EEVblog](https://youtu.be/jNmlxBXEqW0), which for me would suggest that there would be problems when hooking into the charger's power.

Here is a crude illustration of how everything would be connected:

[image]

**Edit:** For anyone interested in more answers, I posted [this question on r/ElectricalEngineering](https://www.reddit.com/r/ElectricalEngineering/comments/xzj6wl/is_it_possible_to_use_a_liion_power_tool_battery) as well.

Comment: You'll spend more money trying to get this working than just buying a wall wart.

Comment: Charger likely gets confused because current also goes to somewhere else than battery. Also, likely no one knows how the proprietary charger system works with the battery pack.

Comment: In theory this can work. In practice your fire safety depends on second-guessing how the cheapest supplier's charge termination algorithm works in the presence of load current it doesn't know about. TL/DR : you gotta ask yourself a question : do I feel lucky? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ky7rHZmk9Yw

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by some comments, we will not be able to certainly tell you whether this works or not. It's definitely not impossible to work but no one knows how the charger handles the fact that there's current "dissapearing".
My personal guess is that whoever implemented the charger algorithm doesn't test for lost charge because this is not simple with battery degradation and therefore a source of problems. But as said, this is just an educated guess.

However, you can test this easily by connecting a resistance between B1+ and B1-.